# Split time into hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to split time into hours, minutes and seconds. For example if the time is 09:11:21 . I need it as 09 hrs, 11 min and 21 seconds.

I have two textboxes to enter the punch-in time and break time. After that I want to get the result in a new texbox.The result is calculated by the difference between punchin time and break time.

For example if the punch-in time is 09:00:00 and the breaktime is 01:10:00. I need the result as 07 hrs, 50 min and 00 seconds.

Comment: re: duplicate.  doesn't seem to be a dupe to me  (though related is different).

Comment: Where does this date? It is a string or a date object?

Answer (score 22):

You can use [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FPJRQ/)**

```
arr = strDate.split(':')
hour = $.trim(arr[0]) + " hrs";
min = $.trim(arr[1]) + " min";
sec = $.trim(arr[2]) + " seconds";
```

**Edit** its better to use `parseInt` instead of $.trim as @TheJohlin told

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FPJRQ/5/)**

```
strDate = "12 : 40 :12";
arr = strDate.split(':');
hour = parseInt(arr[0]) + " hrs";
min = parseInt(arr[1]) + " min";
sec = parseInt(arr[2]) + " seconds";
```

Comment: Use `parseInt` to convert it to an actual number!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.replace`

```
var xDate="12:35:45";
alert(xDate.replace(":"," hrs, ").replace(":"," Min and ") + " secs.");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwtzb/)