# Get the time from a date string

Tags: javascript, date, time

How do I get the time from the date string using JavaScript.

My datestring is in the following way: 2013-04-08T10:28:43Z

How to split the time in hours and minutes format. I want to show the activity stream in the following way:

xxx has updated 2hrs ago
yyy has updated 3min ago

Comment: You can have look at this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878705/how-can-i-split-time-into-hours-minutes-and-seconds>

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp - tutorial

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp - JavaScript Date Object reference

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript Date ISO8601](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228302/javascript-date-iso8601)

Answer (score 22):

Just create new Date object:

```
var myDate = new Date("2013-04-08T10:28:43Z");

var minutes = myDate.getMinutes();
var hours = myDate.getHours();
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? JavaScript supports ISO 8601 format out of the box.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly right. also var seconds = myDate.getSeconds();

Answer (score 2):

Simple Javascript is more than enough:
Date.parse will convert your string to timestamp:

```
var date_string = '2013-04-08T10:28:43Z';

var your_date_object = new Date();
your_date_object.setTime(Date.parse( date_string ));

var min = your_date_object.getUTCMinutes();
var hour = your_date_object.getUTCHours();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Extract a date from your dateString**

First extract the numbers with

```
var sp = dateString.match(/\d+/g)
```

Then you can build a Date object or skip this step

```
var dateObject = new Date(+sp[0], +sp[1]-1, +sp[2], +sp[3], +sp[4], +sp[5])
```

And call `getHours` and `getMinutes` on this Date object.

If you skip this then directly get `+sp[3]` for hours and `+sp[4]` for minutes.



**Compute the difference**

Since you seem to have to compare with now, you will get time difference this way:

```
var timeDifference = new Date(new Date - dateObject);
```

And then call `getHours` and `getMinutes` on `timeDifference`.

Answer (score 0):

This is whats known as an ISO string. There are utilities to parse ISO strings as regular JavaScript dates out there such as Dojo.

```
var date = dojo.date.stamp.fromISOString("2013-04-08T10:28:43Z");
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/date/stamp.html

Answer (score -1):

```
var curr_date = new Date();
var test_date = new Date("2016-01-08 10:55:43");

hours_diff=Math.abs(test_date.getHours()-curr_date.getHours());
minutes_diff=Math.abs(test_date.getHours()*60+test_date.getMinutes()-curr_date.getHours()*60-curr_date.getMinutes());
console.log("xxx has updated "+hours_diff+" hours ago");
console.log("xxx has updated "+minutes_diff+" minutes ago"); //not so beautiful

///STILL IF THE date is a string and !!NOT CREATED with DATE 
/// "Get the time from a date string" might have this solution

var date = "2016-01-08 10:55:43";
var hours = date.slice(-8);

console.log("hours and minutes string is "+hours);
```

[fiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/haidu_bogdan/tpLx2d4j/)